# Singleton timer for iphone app along with synchronisation in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, timer, singleton, swift2

I'm really not sure how to solve below scenario for my iphone app which is written in swift2. Below is the description :

1. In my iphone app, there is function A which is called at various screens of the app.

   Func A() // takes 10 seconds to execute
   {
        // this function creates multiple threads and is time consuming function.

   }

2.Scenarios where function A is called

a.In background i need to call fun A() at every 10 min. So using a timer.

b.In app, on Screen 1 need to call function A() on button click. No need of timer.

c.In app, Screen 2 function A() needs to be called at every 4 min. So using again another timer.

Now considering the above scenarios, it is possible that at some point both the timer may trigger simultaneously or button click can trigger at any time.
I want to synchronise it so as avoid any crash. Please suggest correct approach to solve the above scenario along with example.

Thanks

Comment: if you are careful that is not going to happen. But you have to code it properly. Scenario a is going to be a problem - why do you have to call it every 10min? Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) if your app will allowed to do anything in the background at all.

Comment: Note that your question is very board. Basically the answer to your question is **Yes**. Probably not what you are trying to get out of this, huh? Be more precise, include code - why is the function taking 10secs to execute, what is it doing=

Comment: as per the requirement i have to call  fucntion A() every 10 min. Fucnction A is searching range of ip address and hence it takes 10 seconds.

Comment: well, that does not sound like a good idea and probably scenario a will not work for you. b and c are easy, where is the problem?

Comment: @sia - ur question is valid.

Comment: @appzYourLife  - could you help on this ?

Comment: what are the priorities ? i mean in case of  b and c , what you want priority of button click or priority of c?

Comment: @alok - case b is priority

Comment: Func A() prioRity:(BOOL)isPrior , and on button click, invalidate timer and initiate your new process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a " @try @catch block functionality to avoid any exception crashes.

Comment: Naaaah, please dont, try-catch is for exceptions, not for the dev's incapability to create non-crashing code.